# python librosa package - How can I extract audio from spectrum

Tags: python, librosa

In case of vocal separation using [Librosa](https://librosa.github.io/librosa_gallery/auto_examples/plot_vocal_separation.html), the vocal and background music can be plotted separately but I want to extract the audio from vocal part and the spectrum of vocal part is located in a variable named 'S_foreground' (please visit the above link for demonstration). How can I get the foreground (vocal) audio?

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow should be as much as possible self-contained so that can be useful to future readers and include a [mcve] exemplifying the issue.

Answer (score 17):

You may have noticed that `S_foreground` comes from `S_full` which comes from a function called `magphase`. According to the document about this function, it can

> Separate a complex-valued spectrogram D into its magnitude (S) and phase (P) components, so that D = S * P.

Since the actual parameter taken by `magphase` in

`S_full, phase = librosa.magphase(librosa.stft(y))`

is `stft(y)`, which is the Short-Time Fourier Transform of `y`, the initial `ndarray`, I reckon what you need to do is to calculate a new `D`:

`D_foreground = S_foreground * phase`

And throw it to the Inverse stft function (`librosa.istft`):

`y_foreground = librosa.istft(D_foreground)`

After that, you can use the output function:

`librosa.output.write_wav(output_file_path, y_foreground, sr)`

To be honest, I am not familiar with these theoretical things (my poor output quality using this method might be a proof), but above is my guess on how you should export your audio. It turns out that the fidelity is very poor (at least in my case), so you might want to try some other software out if you really care about the audio quality.

Comment: it is working, but like you said the quality is very poor

Answer (score 1):

the answer of @Alioth is working except:

```
librosa.output.write_wav(output_file_path, y_foreground, sr)
```

which the **output** method in librosa is deprecated, so the alternative solution could be the **soundfile**:

```
import soundfile as sf
sf.write('your_output_path.wav', y_foreground, sr)
```